# Difference between started, formed, introduced, originated and designed

Tags: difference

What is the difference between started, formed, introduced, originated and designed. In my opinion, designed is like starting a trail and the word originated is like COVID-19 is originated from Wuhan.

Comment: can you provide a little bit of context to this question ?

Comment: They would all be used in different contexts. If you design something, you plan what it is going to look like; nothing to do with trails.

Answer (score 0):

Designed to me means like you design a heritage trail so that a group of people living in the neighbourhood understands the culture of people living in the place in the past. That’s just my opinion. Not sure if it is right...